# How to put mysqli while result into one variable and echo it in html

Tags: php, html, mysqli

How do I put ALL the while result in mysqli select into one variable and echo into the html document?

Code are based on W3school
PHP

```
    $sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
//previously it was  echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "
";
$parsedcontent = '<div class="col-md-4">'.$row["firstname"].'</div><div class="col-md-4">'.$row["lastname"].'</div>';
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $parsedcontent; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to concatenate the string using `.=` -> `$parsedcontent .= '<div class="col-md-4">'...`

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array();
// output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    // push retrieved data to data array in order for return later
    array_push($data, $row);
}
```